# Integrating $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}} dx $

Tags: integration

How to integrate 
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{1+x^4}} dx $$

Comment: Ask [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate[%281%2Bx^4%29^%28-1%2F4%29%2Cx]&dataset=). Then decide if there are chances you will be able to get this answer yourself and if yes, what kind of things one should apply.

Answer (score 8):

$$ \begin{aligned}
\int\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{x^4 + 1}} &=\int\frac{1}{x\,\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{1 + 1/x^4}}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{aligned}
$$
Now, set $ u=\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{1+1/x^4} $. Then,
$$ u^4 - 1 = \frac{1}{x^4} $$
$$ 4u^3\,\mathrm{d}u = -4\frac{1}{x^4}\frac{1}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x $$
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} = -\frac{u^3}{u^4 - 1}\,\mathrm{d}u $$
$$
\begin{aligned}
\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{x^4+1}}&=-\int\frac{u^2}{u^4 - 1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\int\frac{u^2 + 1 - 1}{\left(u^2 - 1\right)\!\!\left(u^2 + 1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u -\frac{1}{2} \int\frac{1}{u^2+1}-\frac{1}{u^2-1}\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{1-u^2}\,\mathrm{d}u - \frac{1}{2}\arctan u + C\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{u+1}{u-1}\right| - \frac{1}{2}\arctan u + C\\
&=\frac{1}{4}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{1+x^4}+x}{\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{1+x^4}-x}\right| - \frac{1}{2}\arctan\!\left( \frac{\sqrt[\scriptstyle{4}]{1+x^4}}{x}\right) + C
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha says it is right. [link](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=d%2Fdx+%5B%281%2F4%29*log%28%28%28x%5E4+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F4%29%2Bx%29%2F%28%28x%5E4+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F4%29+-x%29%29+-+%281%2F2%29*arctan%28%28%28x%5E4+%2B+1%29%5E%281%2F4%29%29%2Fx%29%5D)

Comment: My bad, I am not a smart person. +1

Answer (score 1):

Maple says $ x {\rm hypergeom}([1/4, 1/4], [5/4], -x^4)$.  This can be converted to MeijerG or JacobiP or various Heun functions, but nothing elementary.

Comment: Why did *user149844* obtained an elemtary solution then? (-1) from me.

Comment: Maple doesn't know everything. :)